# Method call and a class inside a class

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm in a college summer class that is going super fast and I'm extremely new to programming in general (be nice haha).

One of our assignments this week is to create a simple calculator.  Here are a few of the instructions.

"The Driver class is the only class with main(String[] args)method.Driver class should call a method in the Menu class to print the menu, and from that method there should be calls to methods in Actions class for respective functionality from the menu."

My code is no where near completed I'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with calling the getInput method that's inside the Menu class.  Per the instructions it seems like the method call needs to be in the Driver class.  However, I'm getting a few errors when I try and compile.

```
Driver.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        String user = getInput("Enter: \n 1=Add \n 2=Subtract \n 3=Multiply \n 4=Divide");
              ^
  symbol:   method getInput(String)
  location: class Driver
Driver.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        String s1 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
                ^
  symbol:   method getInput(String)
  location: class Driver
Driver.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        String s2 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
                ^
 symbol:   method getInput(String)
 location: class Driver
Driver.java:14: error: non-static variable user cannot be referenced from a static context
        int userInt = Integer.parseInt(user);
                                   ^
Driver.java:70: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class Driver.Menu
        public static String getInput(String prompt) {
                             ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
5 errors
```

................

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Driver {

String user = getInput("Enter: \n 1=Add \n 2=Subtract \n 3=Multiply \n 4=Divide");

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String s1 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
    String s2 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");

    int userInt = Integer.parseInt(user);
    double result = 0;

    switch (userInt) {
    case 1:
        result = addValues(s1, s2);
        break;
    case 2:
        result = subtractValues(s1, s2);
        break;
    case 3:
        result = multiplyValues(s1, s2);
        break;  
    case 4:
        result = divideValues(s1, s2);
        break;  

    default:
        System.out.println("You entered an incorrect value");
    }

    System.out.println("The answer is " + result);
}

private static double divideValues(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    double result = d1 / d2;
    return result;
}

private static double multiplyValues(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    double result = d1 + d2;
    return result;
}

private static double subtractValues(String s1, String s2) {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    double result = d1 - d2;
    return result;
}

private static double addValues(String s1, String s2)
        throws NumberFormatException {
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    double result = d1 + d2;
    return result;
}



public class Menu { 
    public static String getInput(String prompt) {
        String user;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(prompt);
        return user = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

}

This post is already pretty long so I won't post the rest of the instructions unless you'd like me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **javadoc** says - *Static methods, which have the static modifier in their declarations, should be invoked with the class name, without the need for creating an instance of the class, as in*

```
ClassName.methodName(args)
```

So you have to change

```
String s1 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
String s2 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
```

to

```
String s1 = Menu.getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
String s2 = Menu.getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
```

Moreover you can also refer to static methods with an object reference like

```
instanceName.methodName(args)
```

**Edit:**

*Menu class*

```
class Menu {
    public static String getInput(String prompt) {
        String user;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(prompt);
        return user = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

*Driver class*

```
public class Driver {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String user = Menu.getInput("Enter: 1=Add  2=Subtract 3=Multiply 4=Divide");
     String s1 = Menu.getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
     String s2 = Menu.getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
        //rest of the codes same
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks M.Sharma!  I'm still getting errors though.  The instructions say to call the method in the Driver class so I do and adding Menu. to the method call then gives me this error 10 times...                       non-static variable s1 cannot be referenced from a static context. If I add the method calls to the main method inside the driver class I only get 1 error that says.... modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Comment: `non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context` means that you are trying to access a non-static variable inside some static method check for that

Comment: @user3862586 check the edit parts of the ans it should solve the problem

Comment: Ok I will, I'm still learning how to work Stackoverflow.   I have another question though if you don't mind.  So it looks like you took out public from the Menu class right? But main is static and getInput is static should I be able to call getInput from main? Also, I took out public and I'm getting this....Illegal static declaration in inner class Driver.Menu public static String getInput(String prompt) { ^ modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Comment: well there is nothing special when i took out public from menu You can use public in there.It will just change the scope to deault(package scope).The error you are getting because you missed `{` as the last line of your Driver class so its making Menu as inner class

Answer (score 2):

`getInput()` is a static method in another class, you should call it as follows:

```
String s1 = Menu.getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
//            ^   the name of the class should come before the method name
```